# Obtaining the href attribute value from each li using the find method

Tags: jquery

I have an navigation menu and want to get the **`href` attribute** from each `li a`

### jQuery code

```
$('#navbar ul li').each(function(){
     console.log($('a').attr('href'));
});
```

### HTML code for menu

```
<div id="navbar">
<ul class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled" id="navmain">
<li><a href="/index.php">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop/sales/">SALES</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop/clothing/">CLOTHING</a></li>
<li><a href="/shop/accessories/">ACCESSORIES</a></li>
<li><a href="/cart.php">CART</a></li>
<li><a href="/wishlist.php">WISHLIST</a></li>
<li><a href="/contactus.php">CONTACT US</a></li>
<li><a href="/aboutus.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#navbar > ul > li').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).children('a').attr('href'));
});
```

Or

```
$('#navbar > ul > li > a').each(function () {
    console.log(this.href);
});
```

But to uncomplicate things, I'd do:

```
$('#navbar a').each(function () {
    console.log(this.href);
});
```

Note that this last one works for all of the links in the `#navbar`, not just links within a list item in an unordered list in the `#navbar`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#navbar ul li a').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

---

BTW, are you sure you need that complex selector? Isn't this enough?

```
$('#navbar a').each(function () {
    console.log( this.getAttribute('href') );
});
```